# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified?

Tags: c#, sql, subquery, expression, serenity-platform

This is my error

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

This is my subquery

```
(select TOP(1) Error from tablename v, tablename j where v.columname= j.columnname1 ORDER BY v.columnname,j.columnname1)
```

I'm confused because I am using an order by clause, any idea's?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The error message says it all, and makes full sense.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve].

Comment: Looks like you didn't understand error message - it says that you should include columns that you use for ordering as select ones: `select top(1) Error, v.columnname, j.columnname1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

you can fix the problem using `GROUP BY`.  This allows you to use aggregation functions on columns in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select TOP (1) Error
from tablename v join
     tablename j 
     on v.columname = j.columnname1
group by Error
order by max(v.columnname), max(j.columnname1);
```

In my experience, this is normally used for date/time columns to order something by the most recent time it appeared.